# Instruction for Angular 6 app switch from jasmine to mocha + chai + sinon

Tags: angular, jasmine, mocha.js, angular6, chai

Can somebody provide a step by step instructions how to change testing framework from jasmine to mocha, chai, sinon for Angular 6/7 app.

e.g. what to do after you generate new app:
ng new MyAppToTestWithMocha

Comment: Something I would also be interested in knowing, although it looks like it isn't supported: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4071